# Kafka consumerRebalanceListener not working

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using Kafka 2 and trying to commitParition inside rebalance listener and its failing with below Exception.

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.sendOffsetCommitRequest(ConsumerCoordinator.java:798)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.commitOffsetsSync(ConsumerCoordinator.java:681)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:1416)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:1377)
    at basics.KafkaConsumerExample$1.commitOffsets(KafkaConsumerExample.java:74)
    at basics.KafkaConsumerExample$1.onPartitionsRevoked(KafkaConsumerExample.java:61)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinPrepare(ConsumerCoordinator.java:465)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:408)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:352)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:337)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:333)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1218)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1175)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1154)
    at basics.KafkaConsumerExample.run(KafkaConsumerExample.java:97)
    at basics.KafkaConsumerExample.main(KafkaConsumerExample.java:305)
```

**Code :-**

```
public void runConsumerWithRebalanceListener() throws Exception {
        final KafkaConsumer<byte[], byte[]> consumer = createConsumer();
        final TestConsumerRebalanceListener rebalanceListener = new TestConsumerRebalanceListener(consumer);

        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(SIMPLE_CONSUMER_TEST_TOPIC), rebalanceListener);

        while (true) {
            final ConsumerRecords<byte[], byte[]> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
            for (final ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> record : records) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.printf("Received Message topic =%s, partition =%s, offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s\n", record.topic(), record.partition(),
                            record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());


                rebalanceListener.addOffset(record.topic(), record.partition(), record.offset());
            }

        }
    }
```

**RebalanceListener Code :-**

```
private static class TestConsumerRebalanceListener implements ConsumerRebalanceListener {

        final List<Future<Boolean>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        private final KafkaConsumer<byte[], byte[]> consumer;
        private final Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> currentOffsets = new HashMap<>();

        public TestConsumerRebalanceListener(final KafkaConsumer<byte[], byte[]> consumer) {
            this.consumer = consumer;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPartitionsRevoked(final Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
            System.out.println(" Called onPartitionsRevoked with partitions: " + partitions);
            if(!futures.isEmpty())
                futures.get(0).cancel(true);
            consumer.commitSync(currentOffsets);
            currentOffsets.clear();
        }

        public void addOffset(final String topic, final int partition, final long offset) {
            currentOffsets.put(new TopicPartition(topic, partition), new OffsetAndMetadata(offset));

        }

        @Override
        public void onPartitionsAssigned(final Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
            System.out.println("Called onPartitionsAssigned with partitions: " + partitions);
        }

    }
```

**Setting:-**

```
auto.commit.offset=true
max.poll.records = 100 // Waiting for 1 sec for each msg
max.poll.interval.ms = 60000
```

So, rebalance will happen as 100 records processing will take more than 60secs of max poll records interval ms. So, rebalancing is happening as expected, but commitSync inside onRevoke fails.

ConsumerRebalanceListenre works for rebalance on new consumer or when consumer dies.

Comment: As I know, every consumer can commits the offsets of owned partitions; but on the time of when your listener was invoked, the ownership is over so you can't commit the offset.

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45560255/commitfailedexception-commit-cannot-be-completed-since-the-group-has-already-reb